# Why does information_schema have "YES" and "NO" character strings rather than booleans?

Tags: postgresql, information-schema, sql-standard

I was taken by surprise to find that the `is_nullable` column for this query is typed as `character varying (3)` rather than `boolean`:

```
select
    column_name,
    data_type,
    is_nullable
from
    information_schema.columns
where
    table_schema = 'public';
```

I noticed that some other column use "YES"/"NO" as well. What is the rationale for this? My initial thought was that perhaps other values besides "YES" and "NO" are possible, justifying something other than a `boolean`, but I didn't see any examples of this in my current database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Using psql you can see the schema with `\d information_schema.columns`, or you can [look it up in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html).

```
                               View "information_schema.columns"
          Column          |                Type                | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
... stuff cropped..
 is_nullable              | information_schema.yes_or_no       |           |          |
```

## SQL Spec

Looking up `information_schema.columns.is_nullable` in the spec we can see it's the spec's fault -- as is often the case with stuff. You can't just erase 9,000 years of legacy. Especially with something that is supposed to provide a dependable  interface. From the SQL 2011 spec,

```
IS_NULLABLE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO
  CONSTRAINT COLUMNS_IS_NULLABLE_NOT_NULL NOT NULL,
```

And you can see the definition of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO` defined in the spec too,

```
CREATE DOMAIN YES_OR_NO AS
  CHARACTER VARYING (3)
  CHARACTER SET SQL_IDENTIFIER
    CONSTRAINT YES_OR_NO_CHECK
    CHECK (VALUE IN ( 'YES', 'NO' ) );

GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN YES_OR_NO
  TO PUBLIC WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

## PostgreSQL's RDBMs-specific catalog

If you don't need the generic standardized interface though, you can usually find something more sane in [`pg_catalog`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs-overview.html). In this case you want [`pg_catalog.pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html). Let's check it out `\d pg_catalog.pg_attribute`,

```
              Table "pg_catalog.pg_attribute"
    Column     |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------
 attnotnull    | boolean   |           | not null |
```

There is your boolean.

## PostgreSQL Docs

The [PostgreSQL docs on Information Schema: Data Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-datatypes.html) actually address this too,

> A character string domain that contains either **YES** or **NO**. This is used to represent Boolean (true/false) data in the information schema. (The information schema was invented before the type `boolean` was added to the SQL standard, so this convention is necessary to keep the information schema backward compatible.)