# Why sys.columns.is_nullable can be null?

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

I'm writing a query that will be mapped to a C# class, and when getting the type of the query's columns, it results that **some columns in sys.columns can be NULL**

- is_nullable
- is_replicated
- is_merge_published
- is_dts_replicated

And in the same sys.columns **there are others that are NOT NULL**

- is_rowguidcol
- is_identity
- is_computed

NOTE: Those columns are bit

I think they should always be NOT NULL, because SQL Server must know the columns' properties.

So, why some/those columns in `sys.columns` can be `NULL` and/or in which cases they will be?

Comment: Yes, but what the OP means is, why the column `is_nullable` itself is nullable?

Comment: @Kin the OP means: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIEOT.png

Comment: I guess that there might exist situations where this information cannot be retrieved like in linked CSV tables maybe.

Comment: The same column is nullable in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` view for columns as well. The exact ISO standard is paywalled, but maybe it is a legacy artifact from that.

Comment: @LowlyDBA Good catch! But looking at the code for `sys.columns`, I think it's more incidental than intentional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that it is not possible for the outcome to ever be `NULL`. From quick investigation, take a look at the definition of `sys.columns`. If I run:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.columns'));
```

I see this:

```
...
sysconv(bit, 1 - (c.status & 1)) AS is_nullable,        -- CPM_NOTNULL
...
FROM sys.syscolpars c
...
```

If I change to a DAC connection, I can look at the columns here:

```
SELECT name, is_nullable
  FROM sys.all_columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'sys.syscolpars')
  AND name = N'status';
```

Results:

```
name    is_nullable
------  -----------
status  0
```

So the source is definitely not nullable, right? Yet if you do the same for `sys.columns`, columns involving expressions around `c.status` are marked as `is_nullable = 1`. That's more a reflection of the expressions / data types involved than the actual possibility of a `NULL` value.

I initially thought maybe `SYSCONV()` did something differently from `CONVERT()` (we can't use the former to check, but I thought maybe it might internally work more like `TRY_CONVERT()`). This is not the case, in fact this is quite easy to reproduce even without any internals knowledge:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(bit_column bit NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.bar 
AS                                                      -- nullable?
  SELECT bit_col1 = CONVERT(bit, 1 - (bit_column & 1)), -- YES
         bit_col2 = bit_column & 1, -- no convert       -- NO
         bit_col3 = 1 - bit_column & 1                  -- YES
  FROM dbo.foo;
GO

SELECT name, is_nullable
  FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
       (N'SELECT * FROM dbo.bar', NULL, 1);
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.foo;
DROP VIEW dbo.bar;
```

Results:

```
name      is_nullable
--------  -----------
bit_col1  1
bit_col2  0
bit_col3  1
```

All that said, I don't know what advice to give you. You could conditionally hard-code that this specific column is not nullable in spite of what the metadata says, or you could play it safe and use what the metadata tells you (which will future-proof you in the event the underlying definitions change in future versions).

Comment: [This dba.se answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/205473/43932) quotes the standard: `IS_NULLABLE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO
  CONSTRAINT COLUMNS_IS_NULLABLE_NOT_NULL NOT NULL`.

Comment: Great advise! changing the type in the future may bring some troubles